# Can't get logined agent within before function in Mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, supertest, superagent

I was testing a login process with mocha, here is my example test case

```
var request = require('supertest');
var app = require('../app');

describe('Example', function() {
  var agent = request.agent(app);

  before(register(user));
  before(login(agent, user));

  before(function(done) {
    agent
      .get('/verify')
      .expect(200)
      .end(done);
  });
});
```

Both `register` and `login` function worked properly, multiple before also executed in order of definition as expected, first `register` then `login` then request. But in the third `before`, `/verify` always say `agent` didn't log in.

If I change the code as this:

```
describe('Example', function() {
  var agent = request.agent(app);

  before(register(user));
  before(login(agent, user));

  it('should login as expected', function(done) {
    agent
      .get('/verify')
      .expect(200)
      .end(done);
  });
});
```

And this time `agent` logged as expected. It's weird. Hope someone can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

mocha doesn't guarantee the order of execution for functions you set as before(). To do that, you should either place all the actions as functions off the same agent call or (more likely) use [async.series](https://github.com/caolan/async#series) to get your before functions to complete in the order you wish.

Comment: It seems mocha does execute before() in order of definition, as TJ said here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mochajs/kIHi4O_pWzA/-6vlO3V-MUoJ
I also tested in my code, it's true.